# Check duplicates from two files, leave not-duplicates at one only (Notepad++)

Tags: duplicates, notepad++

How do i check for duplicates on two files (file1.txt & file2.txt)?

So there are same lines on file1.txt that are on file2.txt also, **i want the duplicates same as on file2.txt to be removed from file1.txt**, so on the file1.txt **i only would have left not-duplciates**?

Can i use notepad++ (even plugins) or any other software to do this?

I hope i was clear, and i guess there could be an easy solution for this, its just that my brain ain't working right now.

Comment: I don'r know of a way to do this in Notepad++, but this is fairly straightforward using an app language like Java.

Comment: How can i do that using Java?

Comment: Read in the lines of file 2 into a map, where the keys are the line strings.  Then lookup each line in file 1 to check for duplicates.  By the way, if two lines differ only by whitespace are they considered duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 3rd file and use the TextFX plugin to sort line unique 
(credit to the TextFX usage is to https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2012/05/16/notepad-remove-duplicates-remove-blank-lines-sort-data/)

[image: TextFx Plugin]

To combine the 2 text files into one you can run from cmd:
`type file1.txt > file3.txt`
`type file2.txt >> file3.txt`  (note the double >>)

Then open file3.txt in notepad++ and follow use TextFX

Comment: With this, you get unique lines from file1 **and** from file2, moreover, sorted! That is not what is asked.

Comment: Toto is correct  solution is in this link 
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158234/tool-in-unix-to-subtract-text-files/158235?newreg=96953ce0f6c1487e9f33faf0c731f294